# How to filter a gmap view?

Tags: views

I have a gmap view that I have set a contextual filter(taxonomy term Id).I want to pass to this contextual filter the tid from the URL.The URL has the format
?q=gmap-view&tid=8 .So I want to grab the number 8 from the URL to pass it to the contextual filter.How can I do that?Do I need to select 'Provide default value'  and then use Php code?What php code should I write if this is correct?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In Views, you can access URL arguments via `arg(x)`, x being the zero based rank of the argument in the URL. So in your cas `return arg(1)` or something close should work.

Comment: The arg(1) is gmap-view&tid=8 ,I need only the 8.How can i do this?

Comment: Sorry, you should use the `$_REQUEST` variable, so here `$_REQUEST[tid]`. `arg` is only for clean URLs.

Comment: Hm,doesn't seem to work.When I put a fixed value,so as to test it,works as expected.But when I put the php code $_REQUEST[tid],the view doesn't work.It seems it cannot grab the tid=8.Any more help please?

Comment: I don't know which version you're using, but shouldn't the arguments be accessbile via tokens like `%1` ?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.13 and views 7.x-3.3 .Not sure how I can use %1.

Comment: Then you have various options, one being 'Taxonomy Term ID from URL'.

Comment: I have already tried that,but no luck.Seems that cannot pass the Term ID from this kind of url ?q=gmap-view&tid=8

Comment: [This](http://drupal.org/node/1373428) may be of help. It looks like the `$_SERVER` variable is available there. Also, don't forget to return the value you want.

Comment: @Countzero,thank you very much.I should "return" the value,so the actual code I wrote is: return $_REQUEST['tid'];   So this is solved